# Firestore adding relationship data?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a table `products` and `locations`.

Lets say my `location` consist of:

```
{
   name: '...',
   address: '...',
   coordinates: '...'
}
```

And my `product` consist of:

```
{
   name: '...',
   location: 'location id here'
}
```

I want to do a search and find `products` within a specific area (based on coordinates).

How do I query `products` based on coordinates if I only have ID of `location` record in products table?

*I store the ID value simply as a string in Firestore as the data is imported through the CSV file.*

Answer (score 1):

There is no linking in Firestore. My thought is that you do a query on your location collection with the coordinates you require. This will return locations with desired coordinates.

Take the location ids from that query and query the products based on the location string you have.

So more limitations of Firestore, for the product query you can make one request for each id asynchronously or use a where statement using the operator `in` and passing in an array of ids to match to. The array of ids can only be 10 or less values or the query will fail. So if there are more than 10 you'll need to make multiple requests of this type.

Comment: that's an interesting idea. Thanks.

Comment: There may be better approaches (which I would love to hear) though this has worked for us to date.